# How to easily reference UserDefaults values

Tags: swift

Essentially my app relies on various JSON calls that rely on values initiated during login. Currently, I am using UserDefaults to save the following values at the time of login:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(useremailValue, forKey: "useremail")
UserDefaults.standard.set(nameValue, forKey: "name")
UserDefaults.standard.set(userLastNameValue, forKey: "lastname")
```

In each view controller that I need to use these values I have been creating a variable to and assign the value of that user defaults:

```
var useremail = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "facility")!
var name = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "name")!
var lastname = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "lastname")!
```

Although this works, doing so seems very redundant and unnecessary - is there an easier way to set and reuse user defaults?

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Check out [SwiftyUserDefaults](https://github.com/sunshinejr/SwiftyUserDefaults)

Comment: Create User model that conforms Codable protocol. Then encode that model to Data and save to UserDefault

Comment: Can please show an example? I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually create a class to manage the user settings, something like this

```swift
class Settings {
    
    static let shared = Settings()

    let settings = UserDefaults.standard

    private init() { }

    var username: String {
        get {
            return settings.string(forKey: "useremail") ?? ""
        }
        set {
            settings.set(newValue, forKey: "useremail")
        }
    }

    // follow the same idea to the other fields

}
```

To manage it you only need to do the following

```swift
let username = Settings.shared.username // access it
Settings.shared.username = "some username" // set it
```

You can create sub classes to organize the variables, it all depends on your needs.

You can also follow the idea of @erictruong, here's a small tutorial [Save custom objects into UserDefaults using Codable in Swift 5.1 (Protocol Oriented Approach)](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/save-custom-objects-into-userdefaults-using-codable-in-swift-5-1-protocol-oriented-approach-ae36175180d8)

**UPDATE**

In answer to a question in the comment, the user defaults can be cleared but they should be done manually

Calling the following function `UserDefaults.resetStandardUserDefaults()` this clears all `UserDefaults` you can also change to empty or if you set the vars as optional you can set them to `nil`

But they must be done on the App Lifecycle, either when the user clicks on logout or when the app shuts down.

You can also create a function to clear only those variables.

Comment: 1 note: I think you are creating Singleton in a wrong way. It should be `static let` and the init function should be private.

Comment: You are correct, it was a error of mine, the answer has been updated

Comment: What does UserSettings.standard represent? I am getting an error saying `Cannot find 'UserSettings' in scope` how can I set my own?

Comment: @MarkLyson it's `UserDefaults`

Comment: How can these user defaults be cleared upon logout?

Comment: Check the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 5.1 property wrappers were introduced which are a perfect solution for this job.

Create an `enum` with static properties and a `@propertyWrapper` struct which controls the access to `UserDefaults`

```
enum Login {
   
    @Wrapped(key: "useremail") static var useremail : String?
    @Wrapped(key: "name") static var name : String?
    @Wrapped(key: "lastname") static var lastname : String?
    
    @propertyWrapper
    struct Wrapped {
        let key : String
        
        var wrappedValue: String? {
            get { return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: key) }
            set { UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: key) }
        }
    }
}
```

Then read the mail address with

```
let useremail = Login.useremail
```

and write it

```
Login.useremail = "john@doe.com"
```

---

Or create a struct and save it JSON encoded

```
struct User : Codable {
    let email, name, lastname : String
}

enum Login {
   
    @Wrapped(key: "user") static var user : User?
   
    @propertyWrapper
    struct Wrapped {
        let key : String
        
        var wrappedValue: User? {
            get {
                guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: key) else { return nil }
                return try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
            }
            set {
                let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: key) }
        }
    }
}
```

And use it

```
let useremail = Login.user?.email
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the next `extension` of `UserDefaults` with auto generated keys which are based on custom properties names:

```swift
extension UserDefaults {
    
    static func key(key: String = #function) -> String {
        return "com.company.MyApp.\(key)"
    }

    var isAppInstalled: Bool {
        get { bool(forKey: Self.key()) }
        set { setValue(newValue, forKey: Self.key()) }
    }
}

// How to use

UserDefaults.standard.isAppInstalled = true

print(UserDefaults.standard.isAppInstalled)
```

This solution eliminates definition and duplication of strings keys each time and make easy and convenient way to work with stored values.

Answer (score -1):

i'm using DataMangers class

```
class DataManagers{

static var FireBaseToken: String{
    set{
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(newValue, forKey: "Token") // this code save your value
    }
    get{
        return UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "Token") as? String ?? kEmptyString // with this code we get our value
    }
}
```

}

so when you want to save some value in userDefault then use it like this way

```
DataManagers.FireBaseToken = "Your Value"
```

if your want to get that value then use this code

```
 let getValue = DataManagers.FireBaseToken
```

i hope this is what you want if there is something wrong in my answer then please edit my answer

Thank you